# MySQL is not showing the history queries after the ETL is complete

Tags: mysql, docker, apache-spark

I am using docker container for MySQL and Spark. Both containers are on AWS Ec2 instance.

Pyspark ETL connects to MySQL with JDBC and start extracting the data. When the ETL is running i can see the long running threads/queries in MySQL with command (show full processlist). I think this data comes from metadata table information_schema.processlist table.

Problem I am facing is after the ETL is complete, I am not able to find the queries of previous runs in any of information_Schema tables. Do I need to do any configuration ? how can I solve this issue. Which schema/tables do I need to refer. Appreciate your response

Comment: Statements that have completed are not stored anywhere in the database. If you enable the MySQL general log, they will be logged there.

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'general_log%';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';  Tried these things. It just log the queries but it wont show how much time it is taking. I am looking for something performance analysis on the completed sessions. I worked prior to this on DB2 which stores history queries and you can extract long running queries .